# Database Projects tables .sql files are copied not referenced directly from the source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I am using a SQL Database project in Visual Studio 2010 to create a database from existing DDL files that we use in our solution. All of the DDL files are stored in our source control for example in the Project\DB\DDL folder. When I add these files to my SQL Database project by right clicking the tables folder and selecting the 'Add -> Existing Item' option it copies all of the files to the project directory structure (\SqlDbProject\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Tables).

What I would like to do is link to the 'real' source file so that if another developer changes that source file I can pick it up in my SQL Database project and build the DB from the current table definition. Is there an option to do that or does the SQL database project always copy the file over to it's directory structure?

As a side note what I would also really like to be able to do is detect error's in the DB creation process when something was put into a DDL incorrectly and halt the automated build process and report the error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will notice, when you add the file, that the Add button has a dropdown option; select Add as Link.